# Passing in undefined as a parameter in a function (ES6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a question pertaining to the usage of es6 functions that have default parameters.

Here is an example:

```
const add = (a = 1, b = 2) => a + b;
```

As you can see, `a` and `b` default to `1` and `2` respectively.

With default values, I can call the function without any parameters like so:

```
add(); // 3
```

I can also omit parameter `b`:

```
add(2); // 4
```

And to omit parameter `a`, I can pass in `undefined`:

```
add(undefined, 3); // 4
```

My question:

Is it bad practice to pass in `undefined` as a first parameter in order for the function to be called with the default first parameter, which in this instance is `1`?

Comment: Thats the purpose of pre defined variables. In my opinion, its totally fine.

Comment: unless it makes more sense to not give it a default (ie, let it default to `undefined`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice,a better option would be to create a feed dictionary to pass into the function. That way you can set which values you like and leave others as is or to another value.

```
feed_dict = {x: 1, y: 2}
```

Then you should structure a function to take in a dictionary and perform the addition on its values

```
const add = (dict) => {
 for (var keys in dict) {
  sum += dict[keys]
}
return sum

add(feed_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I posted an answer with this implementation.

Comment: If you're open to this much refactoring, there's little reason to use an object when you could just use an array. This answer also hasn't declared `keys` anywhere, and using `for...in` is kind of a bad idea since enumerable props in the prototype chain could cause issues.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [JonathanMitchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3844713/jonathanmitchell) for suggesting the object parameter.

```
const add = (args = {}) => {
    const a = args.a || 1;
    const b = args.b || 2;
    return a + b;
}
```

Examples:

```
add(); // 3
add({a: 2}) // 4
add({b: 3}); // 5
```

**Edit:**

[loganfsmyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785065/loganfsmyth) offered a much better solution.

> using || is bad form because if you pass 0 it would also use the default.

A better and more compact solution:

```
const add = ({a = 1, b = 2} = {}) => a + b
```

Logan used ES6's [deconstruction assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (see "Default" values) to assign `a` and `b` default values in the event that such parameters evaluate to `undefined`.

Comment: Good answer, it's definitely wise to use the OR operation to make sure you don't error out as seen in  args.a || 1 in this implementation.

Comment: If you want defaults you can do `({a = 1, b = 2} = {}) =>  a + b`, using `||` is bad form because if you pass `0` it would also use the default.

Comment: @loganfsmyth That works much better, and it's more compact.  Care to explain the `{a = 1, b = 2} = {}`?  I'm familiar with deconstructing in es6, but I'm struggling to wrap my head around this.  Or is this not deconstruction?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Oh, nevermind!  I found it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (under "Default values").  Thank you for providing your solution.

Answer (score 1):

That's usually not the best choice -- default parameters should be structured so that the second is only used if the first is also used, the third is only used if the first two are used, and so on, so you don't have the issue of passing in `undefined`.

There doesn't appear to be a standard way to only set a value for the second parameter, e.g. `add({b: 5})` unless you redefine the function to take an object, so passing in `undefined` appears to be the only option.

MDN does that in their documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters), see "Examples / Passing undefined".

Comment: Yeah, I understand why it isn't the best choice.  In my actual code, I have a function `const showPrompt = (duration = 0.667, timeout = 0) => ...`.  It's actually a Redux action creator that dispatches a function to show part of my UI and has a setTimeout for `timeout`.  Most of the time I find myself passing in the same duration, so I just wanted to skip that first parameter.